# Maven compile verson in jar or war filename

Tags: java, maven

This is my war file name:

myproject.war

but rather it should be:
myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

So I thought it is pretty easy. I just added this in my pom.xml :

1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

But still maven built a file called myproject.war  .

What can I do to get Maven to give my a file  myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war

Thanks!

pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.mycompany.area27</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <description>Rest based Proxy Server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
      :
      :
```

Comment: Can you post your pom file?

Comment: Yes I posted now.  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> had no effect

Comment: You have to change the layout type for the spring-boot-maven-plugin otherwise you will not get a `jar` file... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-layout (also recommend to upgrade to most recent version of spring boot)...If you package as a war I suppose you would like to deploy to tomcat instead of using the package tomcat/undertow...instead so you have to change the configuration in several way (please consult the documentation)...

Comment: Furthermore I suppose that you have defined a `<finalName>..</finalName>` in your pom file which you haven't shown..that will change the name in the `target` directory but will not change the name used for `mvn deploy` or `mvn install`...

Comment: Thanks so much. As you suggested there was a <finalName> tag in the pom which overwrote the version. Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml file at the top change the value of `artifactId` tag, this will change the name of the .war file

Comment: did not work for me ! Also I do not want to mess with artifact-Id

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml, if there is a parent then value in
`<parent>...<version>` tag is picked, otherwise value in
`<version>` of artifact.

Comment: The problem is my parent is  <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: Using the pom file provided by you, I am able to generate myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war. Can you please also provide logs of mvn install?

Comment: As another user already suggested. In my pom.xml there was a <finalName> tag which always overwrote the version . Removing it solved my problem :-)

Comment: good to know :)